# Image rotation (bi-linear interpolation and nearest neighbor)

Tags: c, image, image-processing

I want to rotate my image. I am taking an input matrix from files `transform1`(should rotate image by 45 deg) and `transform2`(do projective transform). These matrices are for the inverse mapping algorithm that I have to follow. program works but gives the output as original image rather than rotating it.

```
void ntransform1 ( char * filename, image * img )
{
    int i,j,x,y,n,m;
    float det=0;
    double** mat = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(double*));

    for ( i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        mat[i] = malloc(4 * sizeof(double));

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(filename, "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (!fscanf(file, "%lf", &mat[i][j])) break;
            // mat[i][j] -= '0';
            // printf("%lf\n",mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // printf("%lf\n",mat[1][1]);
    det = (mat[0][0]*mat[1][1]) - (mat[0][1]*mat[1][0])
        - (mat[0][0]*mat[1][2]*mat[2][1])
        + (mat[2][0]*mat[0][1]*mat[1][2])
        + (mat[0][2]*mat[1][0]*mat[2][1])
        - (mat[0][2]*mat[1][1]*mat[2][0]);

    // inverse of matrix is
    mat[0][0] =  (mat[1][1]-(mat[1][2]*mat[2][1])) / det;
    mat[0][1] = -(mat[0][1]-(mat[0][2]*mat[2][1])) / det;
    mat[0][2] = ((mat[0][1]*mat[1][2])-(mat[0][2]*mat[1][1])) / det;
    mat[1][0] = -(mat[1][0]-(mat[1][2]*mat[2][0])) / det;
    mat[1][1] = (mat[0][0]-(mat[0][2]*mat[2][0])) / det;
    mat[1][2] = -((mat[0][0]*mat[1][2])-(mat[0][2]*mat[1][0])) / det;
    mat[2][0] = ((mat[1][0]*mat[2][1])-(mat[1][1]*mat[2][0])) / det;
    mat[2][1] = -((mat[0][0]*mat[2][1])-(mat[0][1]*mat[2][0])) / det;
    mat[2][2] = ((mat[0][0]*mat[0][2])-(mat[0][1]*mat[1][0])) / det;

    for(y=0;y<img->y;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<img->x;x++)
        {
            double xnew,ynew;
            // calculating the new rotated pixel value
            xnew = (float)(((x-(img->x)/2))
                 * (mat[0][0]))+((y-(img->y)/2)
                 * (mat[0][1]))+mat[0][2]+(img->x)/2;
            ynew = (float)(((x-(img->x)/2))
                 * (mat[1][0]))+((y-(img->y)/2)
                 * (mat[1][1]))+mat[1][2]+(img->y)/2;
            m = (int)round(xnew);
            n = (int)round(ynew);
            image2[n][m];
        }
    }
}

void bitransform1 ( char * filename, image * img )
{
    int i,j;
    float det=0;
    /*matrix*/

    double** mat = malloc(1000000 * sizeof(double*)); 
    for(i=0;i<1000000;++i)
        mat[i]=malloc(4*sizeof(double));

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(filename, "r");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {

            if (!fscanf(file, "%lf", &mat[i][j])) break;
            // mat[i][j] -= '0'; 
            // printf("%lf\n",mat[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    // printf("%lf\n",mat[1][1]);
    det = (mat[0][0]*mat[1][1])-(mat[0][1]*mat[1][0])-(mat[0][0]*mat[1][2]*mat[2][1])+(mat[2][0]*mat[0][1]*mat[1][2])+(mat[0][2]*mat[1][0]*mat[2][1])-(mat[0][2]*mat[1][1]*mat[2][0]);

    // inverse of matrix is
    mat[0][0]=(mat[1][1]-(mat[1][2]*mat[2][1]))/det;
    mat[0][1]=-(mat[0][1]-(mat[0][2]*mat[2][1]))/det;
    mat[0][2]=((mat[0][1]*mat[1][2])-(mat[0][2]*mat[1][1]))/det;
    mat[1][0]=-(mat[1][0]-(mat[1][2]*mat[2][0]))/det;
    mat[1][1]=(mat[0][0]-(mat[0][2]*mat[2][0]))/det;
    mat[1][2]=-((mat[0][0]*mat[1][2])-(mat[0][2]*mat[1][0]))/det;
    mat[2][0]=((mat[1][0]*mat[2][1])-(mat[1][1]*mat[2][0]))/det;
    mat[2][1]=-((mat[0][0]*mat[2][1])-(mat[0][1]*mat[2][0]))/det;
    mat[2][2]=((mat[0][0]*mat[0][2])-(mat[0][1]*mat[1][0]))/det;


int y,x,m,n;
double xfrac,yfrac,gray_new;

for(y=0;y<img->y;y++)
{
    for(x=0;x<img->x;x++)
    {

        double xnew,ynew;
// caclulating the new rotated pixel value
  xnew=(((x-(img->x)/2))*(mat[0][0]))+((y-(img->y)/2)*(mat[0][1]))+mat[0][2]+(img->x)/2;
  ynew=(((x-(img->x)/2))*(mat[1][0]))+((y-(img->y)/2)*(mat[1][1]))+mat[1][2]+(img->y)/2;
  m=(int)floor(xnew);
  n=(int)floor(ynew);
  xfrac=xnew-m;
  yfrac=ynew-n;

// calculating the 4 neighbors of the pixel
if (m >= 0 && m+1 < img->x && n >= 0 && n+1 < img->y)
 {
    gray_new = (1.0 - yfrac)*(1.0 - xfrac)*image1[n][m] + (1.0-xfrac)*(yfrac) *image1[n][m+1] + (1.0-yfrac)*( xfrac)*image1[n+1][m] + xfrac*yfrac *image1[n+1][m+1];

    image2[y][x] = (unsigned char)gray_new;
      } 
else if (m+1 == img->x && n >= 0 && n < img->y || n+1 == img->y && m >= 0 && m <img->x)
 {
    //image2[y][x] = image1[n][m];
      }
 else
 {
    image2[y][x] = 255;
      }
}
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure ALL UPPERCASE is not helping your case. And you should add an actual question; at the moment, this is just "I want to do image rotation, here is my code". Does it not work? What doesn't work? What should it do? What does it do instead?

Comment: it does work but in the output its just giving the original image!! for transform1.txt it should rotate the input image by 45 degrees and for transform2.txt it should do projective transformation, but its giving the output as the input image itself

Comment: Add that to the question - you can [edit] it.

Comment: I started formatting your code, which is a execrable mess, but I grew too weary.  What a mess, no wonder you have little idea what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything to your target image `image2`. Basically, the code should go something like this:

```
for (y = 0; y < img->y; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < img->x; x++) {
        int X = (x - img->x / 2) * c - (y - img->y / 2) * s + img2->x / 2;
        int Y = (x - img->x / 2) * s - (y - img->y / 2) * c + img2->y / 2;

        if (X >= 0 && X < img2->x && Y >= 0 && Y <=img2->y) {
            img2->data[y][x] = img->data[Y][X];
        }
    }
}
```

where `x`and `y` are pixel coordinates of the target image `img2` and `X`and `Y` are pixel coordinates of the source image `img`.

Your code has many peculiarities:

- You allocate a two-level vector of 1000000 × 4 doubles in order to hold a 3×3 rotation matrix. Why do you want to use a 3d rotation matrix anyway? (I gather the third column is the translation vector.)
- What are `image` and `image2? Are they global arrays? Shouldn't the pixel values be part of the image struct?
- Your code yould benefit from modularisation: Write a function to read a matrix; another function to invert it and so on. At the moment, you have a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: yes image1 is an array for taking the input image and image2 is for taking the output image... and I have to use bilinear interpolation, so I have to take 4 neighboring pixels, which you have not taken in this case

Comment: This statement: `image2[n][m];`doesn't do anything. You must assign to `image2` somehow. You do that in the second function, though. Have you tried to debug and find yout what the calculated coordinates are?